# separating voice and music from a audio file in iOS App(Making karaoke)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, core-audio

I am working on music app and want to add a feature in which App can convert a song into karaoke. I am studying CoreAudio framework . is there any way of handling it.
Any link or resource related to it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, separating instrumentals and vocals can't be done by filtering, as the audio spectrum frequency range of vocals and instrumentals overlap quite a bit.

For stereo music where the main vocal is panned dead-center, and with the instrumental music panned off to one side or the other, one can remove some of the vocals in the mix by subtracting one channel from the other (say the left from the right). To do this subtraction, you would have to convert the mp3 into uncompressed audio of raw PCM samples, and work with C data types.

A search term for academic research on how this might be accomplished is "blind source separation".

There isn't so much an "algorithm" as a "trick" but it could be automated in code. It works mostly for stereo tracks with where the vocals are centered. If the vocals are centered, they manifest equally in both tracks. If you invert one of the tracks and then merge them back together, the wave forms of the center vocals cancel out and are virtually removed. You can do this manually with most good audio editors like audacity. It doesn't give you perfect results and the rest of the audio suffers a bit too but it makes for great karaoke tracks.

Comment: It's like trying to pull out all of the individual food ingredients after it's been mixed up in a blender.